# Set an image sprite depending on the lowest common number in a set

Tags: c#, cyclomatic-complexity

In my game you can earn either a bronze, silver or gold medal. There is 4 difficulties which you can earn a medal on.

I want to display a medal depending on the lowest common medal earnt if that makes sense.

So if the user has bronze in 3 and gold in the other, it will display bronze.

Gold in 3 of them but no medal in 1. it wont display anything.

2 silver and 2 gold will display silver.

```
    int easyMedal = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("EasyModeMedal");
    int mediumMedal = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MediumModeMedal");
    int hardMedal = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HardModeMedal");
    int insaneMedal = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("InsaneModeMedal");

    if (easyMedal != 0 && mediumMedal != 0 && hardMedal != 0 && insaneMedal !=0)
    {
        enduranceMedal.SetActive(true);
        Image enduranceImage = enduranceMedal.GetComponent<Image>();

        if (easyMedal == 1)
        {
             enduranceImage.sprite = bronzeSprite;

        } else if (easyMedal == 2)
        {
            if (mediumMedal < 2 || hardMedal < 2 || insaneMedal < 2)
            {
                enduranceImage.sprite = bronzeSprite;
            } else {
                enduranceImage.sprite = silverSprite;
            }
        } else
        {
            if (mediumMedal < 3 || hardMedal < 3 || insaneMedal < 3)
            {
                if (mediumMedal == 1 || hardMedal == 1 || insaneMedal == 1)
                {
                    enduranceImage.sprite = bronzeSprite;
                } else 
                {
                    enduranceImage.sprite = silverSprite;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                enduranceImage.sprite = goldSprite;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the first 4 variables get each difficulties medal. 0 = no medal, 1 = bronze, 2 = silver and 3 = gold.

I then have a long and confusing if-statement to determine what medal should be shown. I'm sure there must be a way to clean this up.

Comment: `Math.Min()` does that. Fictional: `Min(a, Min(b, Min(c, d)))`

Comment: ohh of course! that will make it so much eaiser, thanks!

Comment: Rachel, you welcome!

Comment: Or a single Min over a collection. `new{PlayerPrefs. GetInt(),... }. Min()`

Comment: Should we promote one of the comments to an answer (hi-jacking the answer) or close this question for lacking context ...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Please add an answer instead of putting advice in comments. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Mast It's now a race between getting closed and answered by Adriano :p

Comment: @dfhwze If this question is about to be closed for "Lacking context", a comment should be left to OP as to why it's lacking context.

Comment: @IEatBagels I know, I have read this: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/lets-not-close-fixable-posts-without-explanation?cb=1 :) Note that the OP is no longer active here. But you are right nevertheless

Comment: @dfhwze I agree that OP might not be active anymore, but that doesn't mean they wouldn't want to come back at some point or that they won't come back to edit their post :)

Comment: I can see there are 5 missing variable definitions, 3 of them a Sprites that we don't need anymore information about as they are only used in assignment. `PlayerPrefs` shows where all the medals come from, but otherwise is unused which makes it so we don't need it to be able to review this. Finally only `enduranceMedal` does something that isn't absolutely trivial, and even then we don't really need to know any more about it. This shouldn't be closed as LCC as we have all the code we need to review it. I'm very disappointed that we have a ton of sheeple getting this to 3 VTC.

Comment: I agree this should be closed (mostly the reason I commented instead of answering, while MAYBE helpful it's not - and it can't be - a proper review)